# GPS data splitting into journeys

Tags: r, spatio-temporal

## The Data

I've got a dataset which contains position (lat, lon) and speed information with timestamps for a set of ambulances.

The ambulances make multiple trips through out the day. From hospital to a house and then back to the hospital, or from hospital to hospital. At each end point they linger.

## The Problem

In order to analyze each individual journey, I need to split the location data into individual journeys characterize by long periods of no movement.

## Thoughts and question

I can probably implement an algorithm to do this by looking for large chunks of time where the ambulances are not moving but I feel like this should be to some extent a solved problem. **Any directions on where to look?**

Comment: You're going to spend more time looking for a coded solution to a similar problem (eg. Breaking AIS data into voyages) that you will have to modify for your application, than you would spend writing your own code from scratch. Just do it.

Comment: This is remarkably like the eye-gaze sequence data discussed at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2711, where various clustering solutions were suggested, implemented, tested, and illustrated.